# Why simulator iPhone/iPad are given different results vs iPhone Retina(4-inch) and iPhone Retina(4-inch 64-bit)

Tags: iphone, ipad

This is my first time to ask questions because I am new here. Thanks very much for answering! I appreciate for your time.

Using **Xcode 5.1.1**

Here is my problem, when testing on simulator or actual devices, the result comes out different. 
See screenshot attached on food image. When i test on simulator iPhone Retina(4-inch 64-bit), the result is correct, food image displays correctly and matching with text.

When i test on simulator iPhone Retina(4-inch), the result is incorrect, food image displays does not match with text.

I also test actual devices, like iPad Air displays correct but iPad3 is incorrect. Food image displays not matching with text.

Can you help me out how to solve this issue? I do not understand why same code but it generates different result.

```
for (NSUInteger i=0; i<30; i++)

{
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"food%d.jpg", (int)i+1]];

    [arrimagefood addObject:anImage];
}
[ArrforAllDicFood addObjectsFromArray:[DictionaryForEnglishFood allKeys]];
[TableForFood reloadData];
```

Code moved and formatted from multiple comments:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; DictionaryForEnglishFood=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    DictionaryForLaoFood=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    DictionaryForPythnFood=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    DictionaryForImageFood=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    DictionaryForAudioFood=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    ArrforAllDicFood=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arrimagefood=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // add English German food
    //    [DictionaryForEnglishFood setValue:@"Asparagus" forKey:@"food1"];//5
    //    [DictionaryForEnglishFood setValue:@"Lobscouse" forKey:@"food2"];//29
    //    [DictionaryForEnglishFood setValue:@"Sauerkraut" forKey:@"food3"];//22
    //    [DictionaryForEnglishFood setValue:@"Potatoes" forKey:@"food4"]; //16
    //    [DictionaryForEnglishFood setValue:@"Pumpkin bread" forKey:@"food5"];//11
    //    [DictionaryForEnglishFood setValue:@"Asparagus Sauce" forKey:@"food6"];//6
    //    ......

    // Add German words
    //    [DictionaryForLaoFood setValue:@"Spargel" forKey:@"food1"];//5
    //    [DictionaryForLaoFood setValue:@"Labskaus" forKey:@"food2"];//29
    //    [DictionaryForLaoFood setValue:@"Sauerkraut" forKey:@"food3"];//22
    //    [DictionaryForLaoFood setValue:@"Pellkartoffeln" forKey:@"food4"]; //16
    //    [DictionaryForLaoFood setValue:@"Kürbisbrot" forKey:@"food5"];//11
    //    [DictionaryForLaoFood setValue:@"Spargelsoße" forKey:@"food6"];//6
    //    ........

    // Add German pronounciation
    //    [DictionaryForPythnFood setValue:@"Shpahrg-uhl" forKey:@"food1"];//5
    //    [DictionaryForPythnFood setValue:@"Lahbs-cows" forKey:@"food2"];//29
    //    [DictionaryForPythnFood setValue:@"Sour-krout" forKey:@"food3"];//22
    //    [DictionaryForPythnFood setValue:@"Pehl-car-tohf-ehln" forKey:@"food4"]; //16
    //    [DictionaryForPythnFood setValue:@"Koorb-is-broht" forKey:@"food5"];//11
    //    [DictionaryForPythnFood setValue:@"Shpahrg-uhl-sohs-uh" forKey:@"food6"];//6
    //    ......

    // Add German audio
    //    [DictionaryForAudioFood setValue:@"aspargus" forKey:@"food1"];//5
    //    [DictionaryForAudioFood setValue:@"lobscouse" forKey:@"food2"];//29
    //    [DictionaryForAudioFood setValue:@"sauerkraut" forKey:@"food3"];//22
    //    [DictionaryForAudioFood setValue:@"potatoes" forKey:@"food4"]; //16
    //    [DictionaryForAudioFood setValue:@"pumpkin bread" forKey:@"food5"];//11
    //    [DictionaryForAudioFood setValue:@"aspargus sauce" forKey:@"food6"];//6
    //    ....

    for (NSUInteger i=0; i<30; i++) {
        UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"food%d.jpg", (int)i+1]];
        [arrimagefood addObject:anImage];
    }
    [ArrforAllDicFood addObjectsFromArray:[DictionaryForEnglishFood allKeys]];
    [TableForFood reloadData];
}


-(UITableViewCell )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([[ UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellPlace";
        CustomCellPlace *cell= (CustomCellPlace) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //  create a uitableviewcell
    //  if(cell == nil) {
    //      NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellPlace" owner:self options:nil];
    //      for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
    //          if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
    //              cell = currentObject;
    //          }
    //      }
    //  }

        cell.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundView = [UIView new] ;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = [UIView new] ;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


        cell.lb1.text=[DictionaryForEnglishFood objectForKey:[ArrforAllDicFood objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.lb2.text=[DictionaryForLaoFood objectForKey:[ArrforAllDicFood objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.lb3.text=[DictionaryForPythnFood objectForKey:[ArrforAllDicFood objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        for(int i=0; i<[arrimagefood count];i++) {
            NSUInteger str=indexPath.row;
            cell.imageview.image=[arrimagefood objectAtIndex:str];
        } return cell;
    }
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [ArrforAllDicFood count];
}
```

The problem is here when testing simulator iPhone(4 inch) or actual devices like iPhone5, the result(text) does not order/match with food image but running with simulator iPhone(4 inch 64-bit) is matched/order with food image. So How can I change the code in order to make it works both with iPhone(4 inch) and iPhone(4 inch 64-bit).

Food image displays order from 1-30 but only text is changed somehow which i have no clue what to do. Thanks again.

[image: iPhone Retina(4-inch 64-bit)]
[image: iPhone Retina(4-inch)]

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries do not have an order so the `allKeys' method can return any order. It is not even guaranteed that the order will be same from one call to another. Adding, removing or changing an entry can also result in a different order being returned.

What you need to do is include the image name (or name index) with the food names all in one structure. Relying on order is not a good solution.

The Simulator is just that, it runs code that is compiled for the Intel processor simulation the device. The device code is compiled for the ARM processor. One can expect differences such as you are seeing as any order of keys is correct.

An Emulator runs the other processors code by emulating the same instructions and the result would be the same order on each device but again in any order.

Comment: Thanks Zaph. Food image is already given name like food1, food1, food3...which it displays correct order but text does not order which does not match with food image. I provide details code so please have a look and would you tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is here when testing simulator iPhone(4 inch) or actual devices like iPhone5, the result(text) does not order/match with food image but running with simulator iPhone(4 inch 64-bit) is matched/order with food image. So How can I change the code in order to make it works both with iPhone(4 inch) and iPhone(4 inch 64-bit). Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: Food image displays order from 1-30 but only text is changed somehow which i have no clue what to do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Souli I have moved and formatted the code inthe comments to your question. you can delete the code comments.

Comment: @Thanks very much Zaph for formatted code, now it's easy to read. I try to copy all and paste it but system is not allowed.

Comment: Let's me explain once more time. As you can see screenshot#1. Running with iOS simulator -iPhone Retina(4-inch 64-bit), the result is correct/perfect as texts are matched with food image. On the other hand, see screenshot#2: running with iOS simulator -iPhone Retina(4-inch), as result as the text are not matched with food image. I still have puzzled why happen. I hope somebody gives me suggestions to solve this issue. I would be appreciated your time and help!!!